# Silverlight prism region events

Tags: silverlight, events, prism, region

In silverlight prism application I have a region (ContentControl) and would like to remove currently active view before adding another view. I tried to use region.PropertyChanged event but it doesn't fire. I can do it in the code where I add new view, but that will scatter my code. How to achieve this? Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static class RegionManagerExtensions 
{
    public static void RemoveCurrentlyActiveAndThenAdd<TView>(
        this IRegionManager regionManager, 
        string regionName)
    {
        var region = regionManager.Regions[regionName];
        while (region.ActiveViews.Any()) 
            region.Remove(region.ActiveViews.First());

        var view = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance(typeof(TView));
        regionManager.Regions[regionName].Add(view);
    }
}
```

Then in your code you can do:      `regionManager.RemoveCurrentlyActiveAndThenAdd<MyView)("MyRegion");`

Comment: I accept this answer but still would like to know why propertychanged wouldn't fire